# Read/write bits of a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, long-integer, twos-complement

I am trying to use a signed long as an array of 1s and 0s. I need to be able to assign any bit in a long, or read any bit in a long. I keep getting stuck because I can't seem to read or write to the sign bit without messing up the rest of the bits (due to two's-complement).  I could use a boolean array to represent the 1s and 0s, but that takes up too much memory.  Does anyone know of a way to individually read and write to any bit in a long?  Or can anyone suggest a super memory efficient alternative?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the difficulty you're having. For an efficient alternative, look at Java's [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Comment: Use a bit set class as suggested in the previous comments

Comment: Reading/writing the sign bit is absolutely fine, it does not mess anything up. Two's complement doesn't matter. Of course you should expect the value to be printed as negative if you set the sign, but that does not affect the actual bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, BitSet is the appropriate library class. Internally, it is implemented using the long and if required grows to using BigInteger. For more info, read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Some example code in [online java ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/f6f0ee80-2ad3-4fb6-a197-aa1e549fba80) demonstrating the use of BitSet.

https://www.codiva.io/p/f6f0ee80-2ad3-4fb6-a197-aa1e549fba80